# How can I get CR3 value?

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, cpu-registers

How can I get the CR3 value?

Furthermore, how can I get the CR3 value of process A (say Firefox)?

Is there any command I could use to read the current CR3?

Thanks!

Comment: The x86 is either in protected mode, or it's not. The processor can't just subtract a fixed offset once you're in protected mode (which linux is), so the kernel needs to be mapped as well

Comment: what i was trying to say is: linear mapping is a property of kernel memory. For example: kernel code virtual address starts at 0xc0100000, and its corresponding physical address is 0x00100000.What I am trying to understand is: why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel.kernelnewbies/37753):

> I am trying to understand in what extend the PGD (page global directory)
>   value stored in the CR3 register indicate the running process/thread by the
>   Linux scheduler.
>
> I know that each process has its own PGD value but what I am confused about
>   is the value of CR3 register when kernel threads are scheduled.
>
> *kernel thread(s) simply borrow latest scheduled process's PGD ( that
>   means, the entire address space)....this is done to save unneccessary
>   TLB flush since kernel thread operates in kernel space and that's the
>   same to all processes*

So to avoid TLB (Translation Lookaside Buffer) flushes, the kernel just uses the PGD from the current user mode process, whereas in User Mode, the CR3 register would change each time a new process is started, as they are located at different virtual address, so their mapping would be different I guess.

Comment: And this is why you, on linux 32 bit, only have 3Gb of address space, the last 1Gb is the kernel mappings, (all procees gets same mappings for the kernel address space). 32 bit Windows does it similarly, but reserves 2Gb for the kernel address space by default.

Comment: Yes. I agree with you. all of the processes have same mappings for the kernel address space. Although they have different CR3, the translation entries of PGD and page tables are same, which is why they are resulting in same Physical address.

Answer (score 1):

But today on intel processors vulnerable to for example the spectre vulnerability, a new mitigation has been introduced: KPTI (kernel pointer table isolation). It makes that the cr3 of your process maps only a very small part of the kernel (only the code / structures mandatory to access to the interrupts/syscalls). Next the cr3 register is switched and replaced by the cr3 of your kernel which is equivalent to the cr3 of your process albeit it also maps all the kernel and the userland pages (of the calling process) with the NX bit set.